# Can I pass an HTML attribute to the function inside *ngIf?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a routerLink which I want to hide or show according to the return value of a function. Is it possible to pass a reference to its own `routerLink` attribute instead of hardcoding the value in the function parameter?

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/some-path" *ngIf="someFunction('/some-path')">Some Page</a>
```

Comment: **1.** Binding a function to a directive like `someFunction('/some-path')` with default change detection strategy would trigger the function for each change detection cycle. It might lead to performance issues. **2.** Assign the value `"/some-path"` to a variable in the controller, run the function once and assign it's response too to a variable and use them in the template: `<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="myPath" *ngIf="myCondition">Some Page</a>`

Comment: You can access to whole element with `@ViewChild` or some other option in your function. So you can access to any attribute or property you want

Answer (score 0):

Setting the routerlink property will result in an `<a>` tag with an `href` containing the full url.

Which means

```html
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/some-path" *ngIf="someFunction('/some-path')">Some Page</a>
```

becomes

```html
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/some-other-path/some-path">Some Page</a>
```

You could get the routerlink from a templateref like so and of course parse the string properly in your fucntion

```html
<a #myLink mat-list-item routerLink="/some-path" *ngIf="someFunction(myLink.href)">Some Page</a>
```

That said, as @Michael D mentions. You shouldn't use functions in *ngIf